# Upload file on virtual directory using c#?

Tags: c#, iis-7, virtual-directory

I want to store audio file on virtual directory I have created using C#. I have setup the virtual directory in **IIS7**. **\webserver\recordtest\1234.ogg** is my path on other machine, now I'm storing directly on this path, but I want to use virtual directory instead of this which I have configured in IIS7 and which belongs to same path.

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"\\webserver\recordtest\1234.ogg", FileMode.Append))
{
    fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `Server.MapPath` method to resolve the virtual path to the physical path.

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(Server.MapPath(@"YourVirtualPath"), FileMode.Append))
{
    fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
```

Where `YourVirtualPath` is the path to the directory you created on IIS (which points to `\\webserver\recordtest\1234.ogg`).